Ubuntu screen some pixels refreshes slower than others after updating to 24.04
Description
I have some pixels on my laptop that refreshes slower than other pixels. The problem occured when I upgrade to 24.04, with nvidia4060 card and intel 19-13900HX. When scrolling through long websites, I can clearly see the pixels form a slope line and a horizontal lines. But when I stop scrolling, the pixels would return to normal because the refreshing result is normal.
Test and current conclusion
At first I suspect it was the problem of Chrome. I tried to drag other windows on that region, and the lines appeared again.
Then I thought it was a hardware issue. But I have a dual system of Win11 and I tried the windows. There are no any problems.
So I would narrow the scope to software issue in Gnome/Kernel/Driver.
Attempts to fix the problem
I have updated my graphic card driver to 550. Here is the output of nvidia-smi:
Sat Dec 28 21:15:45 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.142                Driver Version: 550.142        CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   44C    P8              2W /   80W |      12MiB /   8188MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      4210      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

If you think you need more logs, I am happy to provide. Thanks in advance for telling me how to solve the issue!

Turning off fractional displaying and zoom the font using accessibility solved my question.
